Can I write one expectation in RSpec which demands a method is called only once with specific arguments?
I'm just finishing my first year writing production code in Rails, and I'm not really stuck here, but the non-rubyness of what I'm experiencing is weird, and I wanted to see if anyone had this problem.
Say you're writing code which involves an external API, so the calls you make to that API need to be carefully crafted. In order to make sure these calls are happening correctly, I want to write some specs which mandate that these calls only happen a certain a number of times and with certain arguments. Something like this:
it "only calls the wrapper once with the correct arguments" do
  expect(Wrapper).to have_received(:do_magic).once
  expect(Wrapper).to have_received(:do_magic).with(flowers_in_sleeve: false)
end

But having two expectations is bad practice! I use RuboCop to lint (and I like sticking to it's conventions) so there are two options for me: either break this into two expectations or disable the rule for having multiple expectations in a block.
So, this isn't a totally earth shattering problem. But it seems very strange to me that RSpec doesn't have a more convenient way to satisfy this case. Maybe I just need to suck it up and write the two expectations. My goal is to do this in one expectation if possible.
This was the main solution I thought of:
it "only calls the wrapper once with the correct arguments" do
  expect(Wrapper).to have_received(:do_magic).once.with(flowers_in_sleeve: false)
end

But that allows many calls to the wrapper, so long as you call the method at least once with those arguments. Which, really, if you look at the sentence you wrote:
I expect wrapper to be called once with flowers in sleeve to be false
This behavior makes sense, because I'm not saying:
I expect wrapper to be called only once with flower in sleeve to be false.

I don't think this is possible due to how chaining expectations in RSpec mocks works. It's a valid case to tell Rubocop to go stuff it. Having two expectations is not a bad practice. Having multiple expectations can be a code smell, the two are not the same.

I figured this was the case, but I know Ruby-ism favors having magical tricks all over the place to make programming easier. I mainly wanted to see if anyone had one of said magic tricks up their sleeves.

You could probably invent a matcher such as .and_no_other_calls but it doesn't exist as is.

Congrats on a full year of working w/ Rails on prod.!
Sometimes you can have multiple expectations that are part of the same test.
In that case I argue it isn't a violation of Rubocop's rules.
Try using :aggregate_failures.
Rubocop will likely be fine with it. ;)
it "only calls the wrapper once with the correct arguments", :aggregate_failures do
  expect(Wrapper).to have_received(:do_magic).once
  expect(Wrapper).to have_received(:do_magic).with(flowers_in_sleeve: false)
end


Did you tried the approach of setting the expectation first and then running the actual logic? In other words code like following it "only calls the wrapper once with the correct arguments" do; # Set the expectation first; expect(Wrapper).to receive(:do_magic).once.with(flowers_in_sleeve: false); # Run the actual code which should test the above expectation.; end. Contd..

Contd.. You are currently using the spy API (ref: https://rspec.info/features/3-13/rspec-mocks/basics/spies/) but there is a count constraint  example given under header Set constraints using the fluent interface on that page so ideally the code you have shown as main solution I thought of: should fail when do_magic  is received twice.

As @max commented, having multiple expectations isn't necessarily bad practice.  It's entirely possible that multiple expect statements can be helpful to cover one behavior. You are free to modify the RuboCop defaults when you have a compelling reason to do so.
That being said, here's a pattern you can use to write specs that mandate that calls only happen a certain a number of times and with certain arguments. You can capture all the arguments passed to each call of do_magic and then expect against the set of arguments.
# lib/magic_performer.rb
class Wrapper
  def self.do_magic(options = {})
    # implementation goes here
  end
end

class MagicPerformer
  def perform_magic
    Wrapper.do_magic(flowers_in_sleeve: false)
  end
end

# spec/magic_performer_spec.rb
require 'rspec'
require_relative '../lib/magic_performer'

RSpec.describe MagicPerformer do
  let(:args_in_calls_to_do_magic) { [] }

  before do
    allow(Wrapper).to receive(:do_magic) do |*args, **kwargs|
      args_in_calls_to_do_magic << [args, kwargs]
    end

    MagicPerformer.new.perform_magic
  end

  it 'only calls the wrapper once with the correct arguments' do
    expect(args_in_calls_to_do_magic)
      .to eq([
               [[], { flowers_in_sleeve: false }]
             ])
  end
end

Separately, consider that this type of test is a "white-box" test (as opposed to a "black-box" test). Such a test is aware of the implementation details of MagicPerformer, the class under test. Generally, it is better to write a test that is not aware of any such implementation details as MagicPerformer internally calling Wrapper. Black box tests enable you, in the future, to refactor the class under test—for example to remove its dependency on Wrapper—without changing the tests. Consider whether it's possible to rewrite the test to expect only with respect to the observable behavior of Wrapper; that is, to expect against either the return value of MagicPerformer or public state that it modifies when called.
